# Global Exception handling in Spring reactor and dependent responses

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to create a web application using spring 5 . It's a micro-service which hit few other micro-services. Response from one service is dependent the other.I am using global exception handing in my application.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public Mono<Response> checkAvailablity(Request request) {
    Mono<Response> authResponse = userService.authenticateToken(request);
    return authResponse.doOnSuccess(t -> {
        // if success is returned.
        // Want to return this innerResponse
    Mono<Response> innerResponse = 
httpService.sendRequest(Constant.SER_BOOKING_SERVICE_CHECK_AVAILABILTY,
                request.toString(), Response.class);

    }).doOnError(t -> {
        logger.info("Subscribing mono in Booking service -  On Error");
        Mono.error(new CustomException(Constant.EX_MODULE_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT));
    });
```

In case of error I want to throw CustomException and catch it in global exception handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionInterceptor {
public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ExceptionInterceptor.class);

@ExceptionHandler(value = CustomException.class)
@ResponseBody
public Response authenticationFailure(ServerHttpRequest httpRequest, ServerHttpResponse response,
        CustomException ex) {
    logger.info("CustomException Occured with code => " + ex.getMessage());
    return buildErrorResponse(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Based on the above code I have two problems:

1. The exception which is thrown in Mono.error() is not captured in global exception handler.
2. In case of success, response from the inner service should be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used two methods in mono: flatmap() and onErrorMap()

and updated my checkAvailablity() code:

```
    public Mono<Response> checkAvailablity(Request request) {
    Mono<Response> authResponse = userService.authenticateToken(request);
    return authResponse.flatmap(t -> {
    // Added transform() for success case
    Mono<Response> response = httpService.sendRequest(Constant.SER_BOOKING_SERVICE_CHECK_AVAILABILTY,
                request.toString(), Response.class);
        logger.info("Response from SER_BOOKING_SERVICE_CHECK_AVAILABILTY");
        return response;
    }).onErrorMap(t -> {
      // Added onErrorMap() for failure case & now exception is caught in global exception handler.
    throw new CustomException(Constant.EX_MODULE_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT);
    });
}
```